# How to merge a pdf file as a first page into many pdf files?

Tags: pdf, pdftk

I have a creative commons license in one `.pdf` file, say `license.pdf`. I want to merge this `license.pdf` as a first page in another `.pdf` file. I can do it manually by the following command:

```
pdftk license.pdf t2.pdf output t2merged.pdf
```

But, I am having more than 4000 `.pdf` files in a folder and want to add the `license.pdf` to all of the 4000 `.pdf`s as a first page. How can I automate this process?

---

I tried. the following outputs came in the terminal.

```
info-farmer-lm17mate@64bit-Lenovo-Flex-2-14 ~/Desktop/LICENSEs $ sudo chmod u+x add-license.sh
[sudo] password for info-farmer-lm17mate: 
info-farmer-lm17mate@64bit-Lenovo-Flex-2-14 ~/Desktop/LICENSEs $ ./add-license.sh
Error: Unable to find file.
Error: Failed to open PDF file: 
   edits/files/2mergedpdffile.pdf
Done.  Input errors, so no output created.
Error: Unable to find file.
Error: Failed to open PDF file: 
   edits/files/A_Vocabulary_of_English_and_Tamil_Words-google.pdf
Done.  Input errors, so no output created.
```

---

@0x450 still facing the same error as above

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290758/bash-script-read-all-the-files-in-directory

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume that all of your "4000" `.pdf` files are located in a single directory (for example `files` ) and the `license.pdf` is directly outside this folder. Then you could easily iterate through each file and concatenate it with your license. This script should do the trick:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for current in files/*
do
    pdftk license.pdf "$current" output "edits/$current"
done
```

At the end all modified files will be contained in the folder `edits`, which is at the same level as `files`.

Make the script executable with `chmod u+x name-of-the-script` and run it with `./name-of-the-script` and don't forget to place it in the same directory where the `license.pdf` file is stored.

Comment: I think there is a `$` missing on the first `current` in the pdftk line.

Comment: @0x450 still facing the same error as above

Comment: @info-farmer Could you try one more time? The `output` specifier was missing and is now added.

Comment: @0x450@Vijay Kumar still facing the same error.

Comment: Did you place all of your `.pdf` files in a folder named `files`? What is your directory structure? Where do you place your script file? I cannot help you if you don't provide any information.

Comment: @0x450 I created a parent folder(LICENSEs)in my Desktop. It's path is /home/info-farmer-lm17mate/Desktop/LICENSEs. In it, i created 2 sub-folders (edits & files). In files(sub-folder), i placed all the  '.pdf's.  i placed 'license.pdf' and 'add-license.sh' in the parent folder.   I wrote the above script in the 'add-license.sh'. My OS is Linuxmint 17.2 (64bit) .

Comment: @0x450@Vijay Kumar@sinclair My friend's programme completed this need.See https://github.com/tshrinivasan/tools-for-wiki/tree/master/add-license